# Woher kommt "Total gaga sein"?

Tags: etymology, idiom, meaning

Woher stammt das seltsame Wort "*gaga*" und was bedeutet es tatsächlich?
Woher kommt "Total gaga sein"?

---

Where does the strange word "*gaga*" come from and what does it actually mean?
Where does "Total gaga sein" origin from?

Comment: I added your question in the title, You can revert it to your old version if you disagree.

Comment: @Gigili: It's slightly redundant, but okay :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [French wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaga) we can read about *"gaga"*:

> Onomatopée évoquant la façon de parler d’une personne retombant dans l’enfance, sens renforcé par la consonance de mots comme gâteux et gâtisme.

According to this *"gaga"* is an [onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) resembling the speech of a child by doubling *"ga"* from words like *gâteux* or *gâtisme*.

The colloquial adjective *gaga* was used from the 19th Century and adopted not only in German but also in English with the following meanings:

> - *slightly mad, typically as a result of old age, infatuation, or excessive enthusiasm.* <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gaga?q=gaga)</sup>
> - *nicht recht bei Verstand, trottelig, bekloppt* <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gaga_nicht_recht_bei_Verstand)</sup>

To further inforce "*gaga"* we can add *"total"*, or "*völlig*":

> *"Ich bin noch **völlig gaga** über diese Nachricht"*
> *"Die waren alle **total gaga**, als sie wieder herauskamen."*

Answer (score 4):

Auf [dieser Seite](http://www.slangtimes.com/wordpress/2011-07-20/gaga-ist-weder-caca-noch-gugag-noch-gaggi/) findet sich einiges, was man über die Entstehung des Begriffes wissen sollte.

Der Begriff stammt aus dem Französischen und wurde Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts erstmals verwendet. *gaga* bezeichnete einen vergreisten Mann, der seines Körpers und Geistes nicht mehr ganz Herr ist.

Der Ausdruck ist eine lautmalerische Nachahmung des Gestammels in die Kindheit zurückgefallener Menschen.

Im französischen Wörterbuch *Petit Larousse* von 1905 heißt es:

> GAGA n. et adj. Fam. Homme tombé en enfance.

Der Autor schreibt auf der oben verlinkten Seite:

> Ein Mann der altersbedingt wieder zum Kinde wird bzw. altersbedingt wieder zum Kinde geworden als Adjektiv. Die beste Auskunft hat wie so oft das Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales; das ist für unsere Zwecke hier etwas zu erschöpfend, aber ich finde dort den Erst(?)beleg für »gaga« in einem Satz von Alphonse Daudet:
>
> D’affreux bourgeois qui ne comprennent pas que si la monarchie est condamnée, il vaut mieux qu’elle meure en combattant, roulée dans son drapeau, plutôt que de finir dans un fauteuil de ga-ga poussé par quelque Parlement.«6

Übrigens:

> »Gaga«, »Gag-gagg«, »gaggere«, »gaggen«, »Gagele«, »Gugag« und »Gäggi« haben mit »gaga« ebenso wenig zu tun wie der »›Gagg‹ (vgl. lat. cacare und caca)«.

Answer (score 2):

Gute Frage, zumal Google nicht unmittelbar darauf antwortet. Eine Fundstelle ist ein Artikel aus dem [Tagesspiegel](http://www.presseportal.de/pm/2790/464447/pressestimmen-zur-herkunft-des-wortes-gaga-womit-ministerpraesidentin-simonis-die-italienische) - Zitat:

> "Gaga" kommt aus dem Französischen, genauer der französischen Kindersprache. Der Berliner Sprachwissenschaftler und Co-Autor des Etymologischen Wörterbuchs des Deutschen, Wilhelm Braun, will nicht ausschließen, dass es sich von "A-A", "Kacka", "Kacke" herleitet. Im übertragenen Sinn habe sich für "gaga" die Bedeutung "trottelig" durchgesetzt. Wer "gaga" ist, wird im Alter wieder zum Kind.

Interessant ist, dass es das im Österreichischen nach [diesem Online-Wörterbuch](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-12555-at-gaga.html) auch zu geben scheint, wo es allerdings auch kindersprachlich "abkoten" bedeutet (was nicht der aktuellen Bedeutung entspricht, aber dennoch manchmal passen könnte).